# MailMessage Mask From Email address

Tags: .net, email

I need to send a email from application with text in the from field.  I have the from email address, but how do I mask the email address so the from message renders the text not the email address?

Comment: This really sounds like a spammer thing to do.

Comment: What are you trying to do this for?

Comment: I think Dedrick jst wants to add a name to the "from" part like in:  "John Doe" <john.doe@example.com>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a name to the sender this way, using the MailAddress object:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("john.doe@foo.bar.com", "John Doe");
```

Comment: MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("John Doe", "john.doe@foo.bar.com");

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s17zfkf.aspx it's address first, then name

Answer (score 1):

[MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.mailaddress.aspx) (that you will use for 'To' and 'From' properties) can take a display name along with the address in its constructor. You need to verify how different mail clients use the value to display (most use a combination of both).